# $\{\alpha_i : A_i \to C_i \}$ family of maps $\implies \exists ! \alpha : \prod_i A_i \to \prod_i C_i$ such that $\pi_i^C \alpha \to \alpha_i \pi_i^A$

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, limits-colimits

Suppose that $\prod_i A_i, \prod_i C_i$ exist in a category, and that there is a family of maps $\{\alpha_i : A_i \to C_i\}$.  There exists a unique $\alpha : \prod_i A_i \to \prod_i C_i$ such that $\pi_i^C \alpha = \alpha_i \pi_i^A \ \forall i$.  Where $\pi_i$'s are the projections in the definition of product.  What I've done is drawn a diagram of the definition of product:

[image]
<sub>(source: [presheaf.com](http://presheaf.com/cache/d5c42z19tz5f2y4h3n1of5v4l401b.png))</sub>

But how do I come to the conclusion?  I am not familiar with how to work with products.  I want to be as non-concrete as possible in the proof.

Comment: Were you in such a hurry that you didn't have time to spell out the words "family" and "such that" in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have morphisms $\alpha_j \circ \pi_j : \prod_i A_i \to C_j$.  Apply the universal property of the product to get a morphism $\prod_i A_i \to \prod_i C_i$.